# Redo in readline emacs editing mode

Tags: readline

How to redo (or undo an undo) in readline Emacs editing mode?

The ways I've found for Emacs (`C-g _`) do not seem to work from the command line.

Comment: Can you provide an example? `man readline` has no match of "redo" (except for vi-mode, but I do not think that is the operation you want).

Comment: Let's say I typed something, erased it with undo, but then realized I wanted it back.

Comment: I think that is impossible with undo, but you can achieve the same with yank and paste.